# Last element in Scala List?

Tags: scala, list

In Scala, List is implemented as linked list. And it has 2 parts, head and tail. Last cell in List contains Nil.

Nil in Scala is itself a singleton and extends List[Nothing],
[as documented here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.0/scala/Nil$object.html)

As Nil is a singleton, does it mean end element of all List instances in Scala has same object.

Comment: Posted here too:https://users.scala-lang.org/t/a-question-on-scala-list/2519

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes and No.

While in fact the end marker is always the singleton Nil, the same object, the last element is the one just before.

```
scala> val a = 1 :: 2 :: Nil
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> a.last
res10: Int = 2
```

You might argue about the terminology, but coders are often positivists in that regard, and truth is, what the code says.

Comment: so it means at memory level Nil is indeed last element of all list instances, but from a programmer's point of view scala tells that last element is the penultimate one, as coder is bothered till that element only.

Comment: I would prefer to say, that Nil is not an element of the list, but a marker, that the list is over. Since List is abstract, who knows, how a specific list is implemented and distributed in memory? Since we say, that Nil is the empty list, it would be inconsistent from that viewpoint, to say, that Nil is an element of that list. The size of the empty list is 0, too.

Comment: I don't think you might argue about the terminology. List is sealed, all you get is `::` and `Nil`. The last `::` has a tail that is `Nil`; its head is the last element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all lists end with the empty list known as Nil.

You can see that this is true by trying to create a list without Nil at the end.

`val a = 1 :: 2` // fails

`val a = 1 :: Nil` // succeeds

`val a = scala.collection.immutable.::(1, Nil)` // succeeds

The last case calls the case class constructor for `::` which extends `List`, hence, creating a `List`.
The code for the case class `::` is...

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

And the operation `::` is defined within the List object, which calls the case class `::` to create a list for you when doing something like `1 :: Nil`.

As seen here:

```
  def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
    new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

You can also see how the code for the `map` operation on `List` iterates through the List until reaching Nil.

Snippet taken from `map` function in `List` class

```
while (rest ne Nil) {
          val nx = new ::(f(rest.head), Nil)
          t.tl = nx
          t = nx
          rest = rest.tail
        }
```

(ne stands for not equal)